# HP Load Runner not running

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

I had recently installed HP Load Runner (Trial Version) on my Windows 8.1 . But I am unable to run it. I had also downloaded all the prerequisite components, then also I didn't get the success. Actually it didn't created the Vugen shortcut on desktop also, so I had tried searching the .exe file in bin, but didn't get it. So, help me in this scenario, as I am a newbie to load runner.

Answer (score 0):

What version of windows? Home? Pro? Ultimate?  It makes a difference.   Also look very carefully at the requirements for use, including credential levels.

Comment: It is Windows 8.1 Pro version. And I considered every requirements and guide, but didn't succeded. Actually I am able to run Tru Client. But none of the Vugen, Controller and Analysis shortcuts or .exe are available to run from.

Comment: Then you have a failed installation